# Popover в bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Подскажите как решить проблему, дело в том, что в цикле выводятся пользователи, при наведении на аватарку с помощью popover выводится дополнительная информация, но дело в том что информация которая выводящаяся с помощью popover выводится у всех одинаковая из данных первого пользователя

```js
 $('.popover-user').popover({
       
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement: getPlacementFunction(_this.attr("data-placement"),280, 190),
        animation: false,
        html: true,
        title: function() {
          return $('.popover-user-header').html();
       },
         content: function() {
          return $('.popover-user-body').html();
        },
       
    }).on("mouseenter", function () {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        }, 50);
    });
```

```html
<div class="profile_friends popover-user" data-container="body" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover">
    <li>   
        <a href="/u{user-id}" onClick="Page.Go(this.href); return false">
            <img src="{ava}">
            <div class="profile_friends_title">
                {name} {last-name}   
            </div>
        </a>                       
    </li>
    <div class="popover-user-header>
        <span id="title-popover-user"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="popover-user-body" style="display:none">
        <div class='media'>
            <div class='pull-left'>
                <a href="/u{user-id}"> <img src='{ava}' alt='Image' class='media-object img-rounded' width="75" /> </a>
            </div>
            <div class='media-body clearfix'>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link-name">
                    <span class="media-heading">    {name} {last-name}    </span>
                </a>
                <small class="btn-block">70 friends in common</small>
                <div class="btn-block">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-border btn-xs add-button">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus size-icon-popover ico-add"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-border btn-xs">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты берешь контекст всегда от первого пользователя

**в этих строках:**

```
title: function() {
   return $('.popover-user-header').html();
},
content: function() {
   return $('.popover-user-body').html();
},
```

Тебе нужно добавить контекст `$('.popover-user-body', $this)`

**$this** - контекстный указатель блока нужного пользователя. При наведении мышкой на поле по идее (так должно быть) **this** будет являться именно этой областью.

Если ты укажешь на неё (область) то класс `.popover-user-body` выберется именно из нужного контекста.

**Должно получится что-то типа:**

```
title: function() {
   return $('.popover-user-header', this).html(); // или $(this)
},
content: function() {
   return $('.popover-user-body', this).html(); // или $(this)
},
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло. Плюс пока из за низкого рейтинга поставить  не могу

Comment: @AntaGonist Выбери ответ как правильный